# Timestamp conversion: Get day, date, hour, minutes, etc without creating a "new Date()"

Tags: javascript, timestamp, date-arithmetic, date-conversion

I am building a web-app and for displaying items in a list properly, I am converting the timestamp attached to each item into a readable format.

Example: `1475842129770` becomes `Friday, 07.09.2016`

For creating this string I am using the standard javascript way by creating a new Date-Object and then using the `getDate()`, `getMonth()`, etc functions.

My code:

This converts the timestamp to DD.MM.YYYY

```
function convertTimestampToReadable(timestamp) {
        var t = new Date(timestamp),
            d = t.getDate(),
            m = t.getMonth(),
            y = t.getFullYear();
        return ((d<=9)?("0"+d):d)+"."+((m<=9)?("0"+m):m)+"."+y;
    }
```

This one returns the day of the week (Ignore the german day names):

```
function getDayOfTheWeek(timestamp) {
        var t = new Date(timestamp);
        switch (t.getDay()) {
            case 0:
                return "Sonntag";
                break;
            case 1:
                return "Montag";
                break;
            case 2:
                return "Dienstag";
                break;
            case 3:
                return "Mittwoch";
                break;
            case 4:
                return "Donnerstag";
                break;
            case 5:
                return "Freitag";
                break;
            case 6:
                return "Samstag";
                break;
        }
    }
```

**My question:**

Is there any shorter/faster way to get these timestamp-properties?
Especially I am interested if there is a way without creating a Date-Object, thus making some magic with the timestamp number itself.

Thanks for your input! :)

Comment: take a look a joda time http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: You *could*. It would, however, be much worse than just creating a `Date` object.

Comment: You don't need magic, you'd need math ...

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao How is a __Java__ library related to the question?

Comment: I believe is easier work with jodaTime, is just a comment, maybe enzo would be interested.

Comment: Sure, there is a "way without creating a Date-Object". But this is much harder than the Date object's way since you'll have to deal with such things as [leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year). And eventually you'll just reproduce the Date object's magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array for the daynames

```
function getDayOfTheWeek(timestamp) {
    var days = ["Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag"];
    return days[(new Date(timestamp)).getDay()];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much nicer than my solution!